# Adding a path for a ImageIcon - Java

Tags: java, variables, reference, imageicon

Hey So I'm pretty much awful at java and I want to add a ImageIcon now I've done this before and I even have the images to work the only issue is the program I am making is for University work and when I submit the work it will be submitted online through a .rar file.

So my issue is currently the image's have a huge direct path so i.e.

**C:\Users\MY-NAME\Documents\NetBeansProjects\UNI-PROJECT\src\IMAGES\image.png**

Since they will be reviewing my work on their work PC or home PC whatever the images wont work for them since it's using my home reference. How can I reference a image so they can open it where ever and the images will still work?

Thanks in advance

-SKENG-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Java Tutorial on How to Use Icons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) has a small section explaining how to use [`Class#getResource()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) when the image is included with the application - look at the `createImageIcon()` method and the description that follows it.

Comment: It's not happy with "createImageIcon" it keeps asking me to create a new class. Damn Netbeans!

Comment: How are you adding it to your project? You might want to create a `Utils` class with a `public static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path, String description)` method and use it as `Utils.createImageIcon(path, desc)`

Answer (score 0):

You can put your images in the current folder or subfolders and then use the following path (for example):

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + "images\pic1.gif"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not use absolute path, and put the images into a subdirectory where is located your sources or binaries.